# Basic question about vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

As part of some question in a more advanced course in linear algebra I'm using this claim which I'm pretty sure is true but a little confused about how to justify it.

> Given a vector space $V$, $\dim V=n \in \mathbb{N} $, and a subspace $W \subset V$ (meaning $\dim V > \dim W$). If we choose any basis $B$ for $V$, we can choose $B' \subset B$ such that $B'$ is a basis for $W$.

So first of all, is it true like i think or am I horribly wrong, and if it is how do we justify it? I guess a prove for $\dim W=\dim V-1$ will suffice.

Comment: One way to think about this is, you can have a lot of choices in which vectors to generate a space. For example, think of a plane -- any two vectors in the plane that are pointing in different directions will act as a basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true...

If you take $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $W = \mathrm{Span}\langle (1,1)\rangle$ and as a basis of $V$ $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, then you have a counterexample, since both these vectors do not lie in $W$.

On the other hand it is always possible to extend a basis of $W$ to the whole $V$, by adding $\dim V-\dim W$ independent vectors.